# Extract word order feature vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, scikits

I'm trying to use scikit-learn to extract feature vectors from my dataset, which is a set of sentences. From my understanding, the library only allows extracting bag-of-words features, like n-grams and ignores order of words. For example, the following code extracts trigrams feature vectors:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,encoding="ISO-8859-1",ngram_range=(3,3))
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
```

How can I extract feature vectors without ignoring order of words?

Comment: Lets move back to premise the x1, x2, x3 are independent variables that effect y as basis of machine modeling. Each word transformed to a vector using TF/IDF is considered independent variable x(n). However, the thought is that word order can itself lead to information gain. One way to achieve that gain is to convert sentence into a separate vector or second way is to use topic mapping like LDA as a vector input.

Comment: @djinn Can you give me an example for LDA? I don't know what it is

Comment: There is a comprehensive tutorial for [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html#latent-semantic-analysis) to achieve what I proposed.